# jquery loads after images

Tags: jquery

Is it possible that any js document "$(document).ready()" loads before images load?

Answer (score 0):

`$(document).ready()` loads when the DOM is ready, i.e. when the whole document is complete in the browser's memory. That is *before* all associated images and style sheets have finished loading.

If you need an event that fires when all images are loaded, use [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event).

Comment: I have used "$(window).load()" but jquery config file loads after google ads.!

Answer (score 0):

Just place the JS before the image, at the beginning of the document for instance.

Note if the purpose of this is not the show the images until jQuery is ready, hide the images instead with css `display:none` and show them with jQuery after you are ready.

Comment: I want jquery loads before all scripts. For example, jquery loads after google syndication script. Google syndication script is in google ads and jquery loads after syndication load.

Comment: Ok then load only jquery in the page, and once is loaded use the jquery get script method to load any other javascript you need your page: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/